# Are there any classes in Java suitable to be used as a 'simulation clock' in discrete-event simulation?

Tags: java, events, simulation, clock

Essentially I'm looking for something that models a clock and can be incremented forward by one unit of time by invoking a method. Anything such as this to be found in the standard Java library? Or would you have to implement this yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a simple integer? - It can be incremented by one: `counter++`

Or the `java.util.concurent.atomic.AtomicInteger` if you have several threads. It even provieds a `incrementAndGet()` function.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong.  Barjavel asked about discrete-event simulation, your reply describes time-step simulation.  In DES time advances directly to the occurrence of the next event, it does not advance in fixed increments, so a counter won't work.  You need a PriorityQueue of event notices, each of which tells you the time of an event and what event it will be.  The PriorityQueue is ordered by the event times, and the simulation proceeds by extracting the next event notice, updating the simulation clock to its time, and executing the event logic.  SimKit (described below) does this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at SimKit. It's a java based open source discrete event engine. It's well documented and you can extract the clock and the event list and customize for your own purposes. It's well supported since it's used to teach an introductory course to DES to grad students.

http://diana.nps.edu/Simkit/

Answer (score 1):

A standard Calendar / GregorianCalendar should do the trick for you.

Comment: If all you are looking for is something that you can add a unit of time to (e.g. a second) then you could just use the add() method on Calendar and just pass through Calendar.SECOND as the first parameter to this method.

Comment: I would try to subclass something in Calendar hierarchy or to use some simple integer counter and wrap it in Thread if needed (looking at java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit could help).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, look into the following:

**Simple**:

```
int counter;  //counter++
long counter; //counter++ (If you expect the time to overflow int)
```

**Mutable** (org.apache.commons.lang.mutable.*):

```
MutableInt counter;  //counter.increment();
MutableLong counter; //counter.increment();
```

**Threadsafe:**

```
AtomicInteger counter; //counter.incrementAndGet();
AtomicLong counter;    //counter.incrementAndGet();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the standard Java API, but check out [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) before rolling your own